# Добавление задачи по расписанию в Celery

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x, celery

Пытаюсь написать свой первый бот на aiogram. Есть такой хендлер:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'subscribe')
async def subscribe(callback: CallbackQuery) -> None:
    id_index = callback.message.text.split().index('Артикул:') + 1
    product_id = callback.message.text.split()[id_index]
    await callback.message.answer(
        f'Подписка на артикул {product_id}', reply_markup=kb.main
    )
    await send_scheduled_message(callback.from_user.id, product_id)
    await callback.answer()
```

надо чтобы при срабатывании этого хендлера в Celery добавлялась задача по расписанию (каждые 5 минут например)

примерный код функции, которая должна выполняться по расписанию:

```
async def send_scheduled_message(user_id, product_id):
    message = await get_product_name(product_id)
    await bot.send_message(user_id, message)
```

с aiogram вроде разобрался, а вот создать задачу по расписанию в Celery, которая будет добавляться при срабатывании хендлера - не получается.
подскажите плиз, как это реализовать?